# Como usar pip de python2.7 teniendo otra version de python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

¿Hay alguna otra forma de usar pip de **Python 2.7** teniendo otras versiones de **Python**, en vez de usar `py -2.7 -m pip install <modulo>`?

Y como se podria descargar el mismo modulo en toda las versiones de **Python**, si esque la hay en la version de Python correpondiente. ¿O tengo que ir manualmente uno a uno descargando y coprobando si existe?

Comment: ¿Y si usas [entornos virtuales](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.7.1.2/)?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de 3 formas:

## la primera es la forma utilizando modulo:

```
python2 -m pip install <modulo>
python3 -m pip install <modulo>
```

## la segunda buscar y renombrando:

```
linux:   which pip
windows: where pip
```

**nota:** tambien funciona para buscar la ruta de python, python2 o python3
recomiendo usar `python --version` para saber cual es la que esta por `defecto` en versiones de linux ya viene el pip con seguido del numero de version `pip[version]`

renombrandolo `pip` por `pip2` or `pip3` dependiendo de la version

ahora solo bastaria usar

```
pip2 install <modulo>
pip3 install <modulo>
```

## tercera opcion [entornos virtuales](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.7.1.2/):

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Comment: La de buscar y renombrar no la he entendido mucho. Es la que yo quiero usar